# Radio Button Malfunction

Tags: css, radio-button

I've styled my radio buttons so they're larger, but they're no longer clickable. This code is intended for a responsive platform, hence the CSS styling need.

Somewhere along the line the CSS (there's no JS for this) that determines that actual functionality of the buttons has gone.

Can anybody explain why?

```css
.container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul li{
  color: #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

ul li input.answer[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

ul li:hover label{
  color: #000;
}

ul li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: border .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: background 0.25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input.answer[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

input.answer[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #000;
}

input.answer[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
<ul>
<li>
<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q4" value="0"><label>wrong answer</label><div class="check"></div>
</li>
<li>
<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q4" value="1"><label id="correctString4">correct answer 4</label><div class="check"></div>
</li>
<li>
<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q4" value="0"><label>wrong answer</label><div class="check"></div><div class="check"></div>
</li>
<li>
<input class="answer" type="radio" name="q4" value="0"><label>wrong answer</label><div class="check"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need code in order for it to malfunction.

Comment: Your questions need to contain the *smallest amount of text* necessary to communicate your problem. All the "hair pulling" and "pint sending" has no place here. Questions should be as succinct as possible and get to the point immediately.

Comment: Apologies - just wanted to inject a little humour into the post. Content has been edited as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Your radio buttons are basically invisible and unclickable. What *is* visible is a big circle and a `<label>`, and neither of these is actually associated with your radio buttons in any way. A `<label>` needs to either either *contain* the element it describes, or have a `for` attribute pointing to the element by its ID.

```css
.container{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.container ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul li{
  color: #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

ul li input.answer[type=radio]{
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li label{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

ul li:hover label{
  color: #000;
}

ul li .check{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: border .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: background 0.25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input.answer[type=radio]:checked ~ .check {
  border: 5px solid #000;
}

input.answer[type=radio]:checked ~ .check::before{
  background: #000;
}

input.answer[type=radio]:checked ~ label{
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="answer1" class="answer" type="radio" name="q4" value="0">
      <label for="answer1">wrong answer</label><div class="check"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="answer2" class="answer" type="radio" name="q4" value="1">
      <label for="answer2" id="correctString4">correct answer 4</label><div class="check"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note the addition of an ID on the input, and a matching `for` on the label. The CSS is unchanged.

Comment: this works well with one radio button string, however when implementing the <label id="correctString4">correct answer 4</label> label into the appropriate line, the button malfunctions again.

Comment: @hellosimon I've no idea what you mean. It works just fine, see my update.

Comment: it did, you're right, it works perfectly. I foolishly didn't match the 'input id' and 'label for' on the final two answer buttons.